# DI principle in Console application

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, solid

I am developing a small game in a console application in .NET Core where the the start of the application is `StartPlay` method of `IGamePlay` interface. I have a class `GamePlay` which implements this interface.

```
interface IGamePlay
{
    void StartPlay(List<Person> ListOfPlayers, int deckSize);
    void PlayFromShuffledCards(List<Person> ListOfPlayers, Stack<Card> shuffledCards);

    void PlayFromDiscardCards(List<Person> ListOfPlayers);
}
```

In my main method I have the following code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()               
               .AddSingleton<IGamePlay,GamePlay>()                
               .AddSingleton<GamePlay>()
               .BuildServiceProvider();

        // Populate listof players
        var gamePlay = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<GamePlay>();

        gamePlay.StartPlay(listOfPlayers,deckSize);
    }
}
```

From my main method, I am directly calling `StartPlay` of the `gamePlay` class in the last line of the main method.

Is this a violation of DI principles? If yes, what is the best way to instantiate it from main?

Comment: No, it is not violating any principles. `Main` method is entry point of the application and is correct place where you can setup your dependencies and call "main" application object. Similar to `application.Run()` ;)

Comment: I just wanna add to @Fabio's excellent comment. This is called Composition Root (CR), where objects are being composed.

Comment: If you want to learn more about the concept of the Composition Root, you can read [this article](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/).

Comment: As a side-note, you should only need to do `.AddSingleton<IGamePlay,GamePlay>()` and remove `.AddSingleton<GamePlay>()`. When retrieving the service, use the interface i.e: `GetRequiredService<IGamePlay>` - This is more inline with DI principles.